# Pandas: moving data from two dataframes to another with tuple index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes like the following:

final_df

```
                                other   ref
(2014-12-24 13:20:00-05:00, a)  NaN     NaN
(2014-12-24 13:40:00-05:00, b)  NaN     NaN
(2018-07-03 14:00:00-04:00, d)  NaN     NaN
```

ref_df

```
                                a   b   c   d
2014-12-24 13:20:00-05:00       1   2   3   4
2014-12-24 13:40:00-05:00       2   3   4   5
2017-11-24 13:10:00-05:00       ..............
2018-07-03 13:25:00-04:00       ..............
2018-07-03 14:00:00-04:00       9   10  11  12
2019-07-03 13:10:00-04:00       ..............
```

other_df

```
                                a   b   c   d
2014-12-24 13:20:00-05:00       10  20  30  40
2014-12-24 13:40:00-05:00       20  30  40  50
2017-11-24 13:10:00-05:00       ..............
2018-07-03 13:20:00-04:00       ..............
2018-07-03 13:25:00-04:00       ..............
2018-07-03 14:00:00-04:00       90  100 110 120
2019-07-03 13:10:00-04:00       ..............
```

And I need to remplace the NaN values in my final_df with the related dataframe to be like that:

```
                                other   ref
(2014-12-24 13:20:00-05:00, a)  10      1
(2014-12-24 13:40:00-05:00, b)  30      3
(2018-07-03 14:00:00-04:00, d)  110     11
```

How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `pandas.DataFrame.lookup`

```
final_df['ref'] = ref_df.lookup(*zip(*final_df.index))
final_df['other'] = other_df.lookup(*zip(*final_df.index))
```

---

### `map` and `get`

For when you have missing bits

```
final_df['ref'] = list(map(ref_df.stack().get, final_df.index))
final_df['other'] = list(map(other_df.stack().get, final_df.index))
```

### Demo

#### Setup

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'd')])
final_df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=['other', 'ref'])
ref_df = pd.DataFrame([
    [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
    [ 2,  3,  4,  5],
    [ 9, 10, 11, 12]
], [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
other_df = pd.DataFrame([
    [ 10,  20,  30,  40],
    [ 20,  30,  40,  50],
    [ 90, 100, 110, 120]
], [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

print(final_df, ref_df, other_df, sep='\n\n')

    other  ref
1 a   NaN  NaN
2 b   NaN  NaN
3 d   NaN  NaN

   a   b   c   d
1  1   2   3   4
2  2   3   4   5
3  9  10  11  12

    a    b    c    d
1  10   20   30   40
2  20   30   40   50
3  90  100  110  120
```

#### Result

```
final_df['ref'] = ref_df.lookup(*zip(*final_df.index))
final_df['other'] = other_df.lookup(*zip(*final_df.index))

final_df

     other  ref
1 a     10    1
2 b     30    3
3 d    120   12
```

Comment: Great answer! However, if other_df or ref_df had a row missing (say 2018-07-03 13:20:00-04:00 isn't present in ref_df), then wouldn't this method fail (as you are checking based on index) ? Just curious ... !

Comment: "map and get" works for me. A bit more of explanation about the asterisk and I will mark as solved

Comment: @Alfonso_MA I've updated the answer to use `list` instead of `[*...]`.  The `list` shows what I meant.  It was easier to just change it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that can work with missing dates in `ref_df` and `other_df`:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(final_df.index)
ref = ref_df.stack().rename('ref')
other = other_df.stack().rename('other')

result = pd.DataFrame(index=index).join(ref).join(other)
```